# What is pipenv [dev-packages] section for?

Tags: python, pipenv

I'm learning [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and there's something I don't quite understand.  Apparently your Pipfile can contain two sections:

```
[packages]
...

[dev-packages]
....
```

As I understand it, the packages section is where the packages that you install are listed.  But what is the dev-packages section for?  How is it different from the packages section?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

This section is for development requirements. So stuff like linters, unit test libraries, etc. All that is not needed on the user's machine.

To install a package as dev-requirement add `-d` to `install` command (i.e. `pipenv install -d ...`), to install the dev-requirements section add `-d` to `sync` command (i.e. `pipenv sync -d ...`).

Comment: Just to be clear, syntax is `pipenv install -d` not `pipenv -d install`

Comment: @Connor I've amended this answer to reflect this.

Comment: Is it safe to say then that installing Jupyterlabs for use in writing and trying out the code should be done as a dev-package?

Comment: is `pipenv install -d` for dev packages **including** the standard packages?

Comment: @carkod Yes. It installs the standard AND the dev packages. As far as I know there is no way to install ONLY the dev packages (which might have been useful when running linters and formatters in CI/CD pipelines)

Comment: If you want to install  only the dev packages you need to run: `pipenv install --categories=dev-packages`